# Prolog adding elements to a list

Tags: string, list, prolog

I'm trying to add letters to A while both heads are the same but it's returning `false`.

```
 :- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

 add(X,[Y|Tail],[Y|Tail1]):- 
    add(X,Tail,Tail1).

firsts(A,[],[]).
firsts(A ,Word1, Word2) :-
   Word1 = [H1|T1] , Word2 = [H2|T2],
   H1 == H2,
   add(H1,[],A),
   firsts(A,T1,T2).
```

My code is returning `false` for some reason.

Comment: What do you expect for `firsts/3`? Give concrete examples.

Comment: `add/3` doesn't have a base case. So it will eventually fail on any call once the 2nd or 3rd arguments are []. In fact, your call to `add(H1,[],A)` will fail immediately since your second argument is `[]` and your only `add/3` predicate clause has `[Y|Tail]` as its second argument, which is a list of at least one element.